# Non-appended element with no reference

Tags: jquery, memory

I would like to know what happens to browser memory when an element is created but not appended to something. For example:

In the case of:

```
var text = $('<div/>').html('<b>hello</b>').text();
```

What happens to the div element and what is its impact on memory if anything?

Comment: did you try this code..?

Comment: yes. there's nothing wrong with the code. I just want to know what happens to the element as it hasn't been appended. does it stay in memory

Comment: wow, 4 votes for closure on an "ambiguous question" without asking me to clarify what the question was. shame.

Comment: I've voted to reopen, it's a valid question even as formulated currently.

Comment: BTW, the code given in the example is valid on its own: this trick - create an element, drop something as its `innerHTML`, get back that something as `innerText` - is ofted used to escape HTML output.

Comment: @raina77ow thx. yes, that's what i'm using it for. it's to add data coming from php/mysqli to a textarea, e.g. &pound; changes to £.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element (`jQuery` object, to be precise) created by this (sub-)expression...

```
$('<div/>').html('<b>hello</b>')
```

... will no longer be referenced by anything after the whole line is executed. Hence it will technically be considered `discarded` - in practice, it will still reside in memory, prepared for garbage collector to reap whenever that little beast kicks in.

This situation is somewhat similar to what happens when one calls methods on primitives, like this:

```
'abc'.toUpperCase();
```

Here `'abc'` will first be converted to `String` object, then `toUpperCase` method of this object will be called (and the whole expression evaluates to the result of this call). The point is, this `String` object will be discarded right after evaluation.

Comment: credit to you for answering this raina77ow, and voting for reopen. thx for your answer.